# password protect or encrypt sqlite db file in python

Tags: python

I am generating a sqlitedb file with below code

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('../sqlitedb/sample_db.db')
```

Is there any way I can password protect this file or some kind of security  in python or generally in windows so nobody can access it.

Comment: Use [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) to perform encryption and decryption with a password from your python code.

Comment: Is it answer for your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381616/how-to-connect-to-a-protected-sqlite3-database-with-python

Comment: Pointless. Your computer if you are admin (if its a corporate environment you are not), then you can set the permissions which is simple, but then you hardly need to protect. If its on someone else's computer they can just read the python password from your file.

Comment: @Armaggheddon could you exactly show me as its new for me to use this.

Comment: @jwal I should use it in someone else's system so I am protecting the python file as well so the code cannot be read or accessed

Comment: Right now i dont have a ready example to copy paste in an answer, I will get one when i get some free time if no one answers. Update: As said, see the answer below from [@Sabil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16555279/sabil)  :)

Answer (score 2):

### This Solution Will Work on Linux OS Only

**Install sqlcipher:**

`sudo apt-get install sqlcipher`

**Install sqlcipher package:**

`pip install pysqlcipher3`

**Sample Code:**

```
from pysqlcipher3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
conn = sqlite.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("PRAGMA key='password'")
c.execute("PRAGMA cipher_compatibility = 3")
c.execute('''create table stocks (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')
c.execute("""insert into stocks values ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)""")
conn.commit()
c.close()
```

#### For Windows You Can Follow Below Links:

1. [Install pysqlcipher3 windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718992/install-pysqlcipher3-windows)
2. [Compile SQLite with SQLCipher on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353037/compile-sqlite-with-sqlcipher-on-windows)

Comment: not able to use the sudo command on windows

Comment: See at the end of [this page](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/introduction/). Windows binaries are not provided so you have to compile your own or **buy** a prebuilt one. Is just easier to use a linux based system.

Comment: @shee You follow attached links